# How to make ExtJS grid to re-render itself?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a column rendering for a grid which draws text in bold if certain data holds true. Now when this data changes, I want to call some method on the grid to make it re-render itself. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does your grid not refresh automatically? Maybe something wrong with your data binding...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's as easy as

```
grid.getView().refresh();
```

Comment: If the data is changing, the renderer should be getting called, which means you wouldn't have to do this. rFactor: how are you changing the data?

Comment: There are some cases such as the `isDisabled` of an item of `ActionColumn` that are NOT re-calculated automatically on model change. I had to use this solution to make the icon work. Thanks!

Comment: I had the requirement to refresh just one column. I used this to accomplish that. It was so fast that I didn't mind the other columns are refreshed as well.